# Select2 search against current list of items

Tags: jquery-select2

Using Select2's search defaults, I see it runs ajax calls with the query terms of the characters I typed.  It does not filter against the current list of items.   I didn't see anything in the docs to control this behavior.  Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ajax'd data, Select2 doesn't have an option to filter against the current, cached result set, or a freshly fetched set.  It always gets a new data set.

My solution was to write my own filter on the fresh data.   It works but for every search term, it makes a new ajax call, which just returns the same data, every time.

```
 processResults: function (data, query) {
            let normalizedData = hj.gic.swapFieldDataConditioner('name', 'text', data.results);

            if(query.term === undefined) {
                return {results: normalizedData};
            } else {
                let term = new RegExp(query.term, 'gi'), matchedResults = [];
                normalizedData.forEach(function (item) {
                    if(item.text.match(term)) {
                        matchedResults.push(item);
                    }
                });
                return {results: matchedResults};
            }
        }
```